# Разница в производительности динамического SQL между bind переменныеми и конкатенированием

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть ли весомая разница в производительности на примере БД ORACLE при использовании bind переменных и конкатенировании для динамического SQL?

Например, если мы подставляем в `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` переменную с типом дата, *ORACLE* все равно приводит её к строке, или уже знает, что это дата и не выполняет неявного преобразования?

Пример кода:

```
declare
  sdate date;
  str   varchar2(255);
  table_type;--Табличный пользовательский тип
begin
  sdate := sysdate;
  str   := 'select * from oper o where date > to_date(''' || sdate || ',''dd.mm.yyyy'')';
  execute immediate str bulk collect into table_type;
  str   := 'select * from oper o where date > :sdate';
  execute immediate str bulk collect into table_type using sdate;
end;
```

Comment: Добавте в вопрос пример кода.

Comment: С подстановкой неявного преобразования не будет. Этот способ предпочтительней.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во первых эти два запроса в общем случае могут возвращать разные результаты, т.к. во втором случае `bind variable` будет содержать компоненту времени, а в первом случае только дату (т.е. время: `00:00:00`).

Во вторых Oracle DB будет обрабатывать эти запросы по-разному:

1. запрос с `to_date(''' || sdate || ',''dd.mm.yyyy'')'` - будет парсится при каждом выполнении, после этого будет расчитан хеш строки запроса и по этому хешу Oracle попытается найти в `Library Cache` (принадлежит `Shared Pool`) не обрабытывал ли он уже точно такой же (с точностью до знака/пробела) запрос раньше. Если такой хеш найден в `Library Cache` и в запросе отсутствуют `bind variables`, то Oracle использует план запроса из Library Cache, т.е. повторно план выполнения не строится. В вашем случае (если использовать `sysdate`) каждый запрос с отличающейся датой будет иметь отличный хеш. Такие запросы могут вытеснять другие полезные запросы из Library Cache, что может привести к более длительной обработке запросов.
2. При использовании `bind variables` хеш запроса будет всегда одинаковым вне зависимости от значения `bind variable`. Дальше все немного сложнее, т.к. Oracle будет анализировать значение `bind variable` для того чтобы принять решение - подходит ли один из существующих в `Library Cache` план выполнения запроса или же стоит построить новый план выполнения. Подробнее о `Adaptive Cursor Sharing` можно прочитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_cursor.htm#TGSQL-GUID-42432DFE-D56A-4B9A-8FCF-94FB86012AFC) и [здесь](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/adaptive-cursor-sharing-11gr1).

В общем случае лучше использовать `bind variables`, но в старых версиях Oracle (до 12.1) иногда `Adaptive Cursor Sharing` отрабатывал не очень хорошо и на практике в DWH-подобных БД **иногда** специально делали так, чтобы `Adaptive Cursor Sharing` не отрабатывал.